# AQuery load image with progress in percent on progressbar

Tags: android, android-progressbar, aquery

I'm trying to load images from website with aquery and show loading progress in percent on progressbar. Documentation says, that it is possible with this sample code
`aq.id(R.id.image).progress(R.id.progress).image(imageUrl, true, true);`
This code works, but only if progress bar has default style. If I set 
`style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"`
 my progressbar will not dissapear after loading end.
And well, of course a progress bar only is displayed when the download starts and disappears when the download is complete, the percent are not displayed.

But if I pass as a parameter to a `.progress` method preconfigured ProgressDialog AQuery updates loading status in percents inside this dialog.
`AQuery aq = new AQuery(this);
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
dialog.setTitle("AQuery");
dialog.setMessage("Downloading....Please wait !");
dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
dialog.setMax(100);
dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
aq.id(R.id.image).progress(dialog).image(avatar, true, true);`

This code works well for dialog. I need the same thing but for a horizontal progress bar.
I wonder is it possible to make AQuery to display the progress in the ProgressBar (View) in percents, like in ProgressDialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem disappears after updating AQuery library